# Which library should I include in CLion to enable readline

Tags: c, cmake, readline

I'm using CLion on El Capitan. Now I need to use the readline and add_history function in my project. But the linker complains those below down.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add_history", referenced from:
      _main in lisp_3.c.o
  "_readline", referenced from:
      _main in lisp_3.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I can tackle it by adding a `-ledit` flag when compiling it manually or  linking the libedit.tbd in Xcode but CLion uses CMake. So I don't know which library should I add to the CMakeLists.txt.

It's the first time I have used CMake to build a project. And I could only follow what he did in this question [How to include C static libraries in CMAKE project on MAC OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662321/how-to-include-c-static-libraries-in-cmake-project-on-mac-os-x)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(SOURCE_FILES read.c)
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_library(readline_lib /* what can I place here?*/)

set(frameworks ${readline_lib})

target_link_libraries(test ${frameworks})
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your CMakeLists.txt. Probably you have to use `target_link_library`, but your question is lacking any effort and quite some information.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of find_library? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_library.html

Answer (score 0):

a link to a tar of the readline library is available at: `<https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html>`

or more directly from: `<git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/snapshot/readline-master.tar.gz>`

I think the history functions come with the readline library.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(yourprojectname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem using:

```
target_link_libraries(test edit)
```

You need your program `test` to link against `editline` lib not readline

And below is the minimal `CMakeList.txt` file to compile it

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(test C)

set(SOURCE_FILES read.c)

add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test edit)
```