# Mac C++ Clion,Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64, Function

Tags: c++, macos, function, clion

i am new ,and use MacOS Clion to develop C++ program , I have encountered no way to solve the problem, please help me ，Thanks！
.h file :

```
namespace VLJudge {

class JudgeProcess {

public:
    static JudgeProcess* instance();
    void fileProcess(const std::string &file_path_, const std::string &folder_out,
                     const std::vector<std::string> &outs);

private:
    static JudgeProcess* instance_;

    bool verifySizes(const cv::Mat &mat, cv::Rect mr);
};
```

}

.cpp file :

```
#include "judge/judge_process.h"
#include "vl.h"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace VL;
namespace VLJudge {
const int DEFAULT_WIDTH_SIZE = 1000;
const int THRESHOLD_MAX_VALUE = 255;
const int DEFAULT_GAUSSIANBLUR_SIZE = 11;
const int THRESHOLD_BLOCK_SIZE = 25;
const int THRESHOLD_CONST_VALUE = 5;

const int DEFAULT_MORPH_SIZE_WIDTH = 15;  // 17
const int DEFAULT_MORPH_SIZE_HEIGHT = 1;  // 3
void JudgeProcess::fileProcess(const std::string &file_path_, const std::string &folder_out,
                               const std::vector<std::string> &outs) {

    std::vector<std::string> files;
    cv::Mat image, zoom, blur, gray, threshold, morphology;

    image = cv::imread(file_path_, ImreadModes::IMREAD_COLOR);

    Utils::resizeScale(image, zoom, DEFAULT_WIDTH_SIZE);

    GaussianBlur(zoom, blur, Size(DEFAULT_GAUSSIANBLUR_SIZE, DEFAULT_GAUSSIANBLUR_SIZE), 0, 0);

    cvtColor(blur, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    adaptiveThreshold(gray, threshold, THRESHOLD_MAX_VALUE, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV,
                      THRESHOLD_BLOCK_SIZE, THRESHOLD_CONST_VALUE);

    Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE,
                                            Size(DEFAULT_MORPH_SIZE_WIDTH, DEFAULT_MORPH_SIZE_HEIGHT));
    morphologyEx(threshold, morphology, MORPH_CLOSE, element);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours(morphology, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<Rect> outRects;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(Mat(contours.at(i)));
        if (verifySizes(zoom, rect)) {
            outRects.push_back(rect);
            cv::Mat tempImg;
            zoom(outRects[i]).copyTo(tempImg);
            string filename = folder_out + "/" + Utils::getFileName(file_path_) + "_" + Utils::int2str(i) + ".jpg";
            files.push_back(filename);
            imwrite(filename, tempImg);
        }
    }
}


bool JudgeProcess::verifySizes(const cv::Mat &mat, cv::Rect mr) {
    if (1.0 * mr.y > 100 || 1.0 * mr.width * mr.height < 510.0f || mr.x == 0 || mr.y == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

JudgeProcess* JudgeProcess::instance_ = nullptr;

JudgeProcess* JudgeProcess::instance() {
    if (!instance_) {
        instance_ = new JudgeProcess;
    }
    return instance_;
}
```

}

Call the Function code :

```
#include "vl.h"
#include "judge/judge_process.h"

using namespace std;

const string test_file_path = "../../resource/judge/origin/1_standard.png";
const string file_process = "../../resource/judge/origin/1_standard.png";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> filenames ;
       VLJudge::JudgeProcess::instance()->fileProcess(test_file_path,file_process,filenames);

    for (int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); ++i) {
            string filename = filenames.at(i);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

and error log :

- /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/liqiang   /Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/6f5d7cd5/6f5d7cd5/Debug --target VehicleLicenseOCR -- -j 4
  Scanning dependencies of target VehicleLicenseOCR
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/VehicleLicenseOCR.dir/src/judge   /main_judge.cpp.o
  [100%] Linking CXX executable VehicleLicenseOCR
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "VLJudge::JudgeProcess::fileProcess(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&, std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > > const&)", referenced from:
    _main in main_judge.cpp.o
    "VLJudge::JudgeProcess::instance()", referenced from:
    _main in main_judge.cpp.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make[3]: *** [VehicleLicenseOCR] Error 1
  make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/VehicleLicenseOCR.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/VehicleLicenseOCR.dir/rule] Error 2
  make: *** [VehicleLicenseOCR] Error 2

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, although with a different library.

I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662321/how-to-include-c-static-libraries-in-cmake-project-on-mac-os-x) might help!

What I think you need to do is to configure your CMakeLists.txt file correctly so that the libraries are being linked at compile time (provided the libraries have been installed correctly on your system).

Usually just a download and then the following commands to install a library.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

#### ON TO THE SOLUTION...

I think your CMakeLists.txt file should contain something similar to this...

## Include the mac os package directory

This is where my libraries installed themselves to

```
include_directories(/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig)
```

## Find the libraries

```
find_library(<LIBRARY_NAME>_lib <LIBRARY_NAME>)

# Group the libraries
set(frameworks
        ${<LIBRARY_NAME>_lib})
```

## Group the source files

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c main.h)

add_executable(Test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

## Link the libraries

```
target_link_libraries(Test ${frameworks})
```

I hope this helps get you on the right track!